# Drush - "Failed to get available update data" for all modules

Tags: 7, drush, updating

**Problem**

I'm trying to use drush to update a module. However all updates fail and automatically rolled back because it can't find any update data:

```
Failed to get available update data for one project. [18.1 sec, 70.14 MB]   [error]
```

It's a brand new environment, but I've migrated in my dev environment using Backup and Migrate.

The problem is documented [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1090528), apparently it is something to do with migration for a new domain. (Although somehow I've never bumped into it before).

The solution mentioned is manually dump the cache_update table, however I dumped it and I'm still getting the error.

On wiping the table and then re-running `drush up modulename`

I get an output like this (I've shown two segments, I get 15 on running it, left out for brevity):

```
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.03 sec, 2.79 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.03 sec, 3.01 MB] [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.08 sec, 6.7 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                          [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.08 sec, 6.7 MB]                                                                                                                                                         [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.31 root directory at /srv/www/mysite.net/public [0.11 sec, 8.32 MB]                                                                                                                                          [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.11 sec, 8.33 MB]                                                                                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.11 sec, 8.33 MB]                                                                                                                                                                 [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.14 sec, 8.8 MB]                                                                                                                                                [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_database() [0.14 sec, 8.82 MB]                                                                                                                                                    [bootstrap]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.14 sec, 8.82 MB]                                                                                                                                                                [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.15 sec, 9.92 MB]                                                                                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_login() [0.72 sec, 63.3 MB]                                                                                                                                                       [bootstrap]
Successfully logged into Drupal as Anonymous (uid=0) [0.72 sec, 63.31 MB]                                                                                                                                                         [bootstrap]
Found command: pm-update (commandfile=pm) [0.72 sec, 63.31 MB]                                                                                                                                                                    [bootstrap]
Initializing drush commandfile: user [0.72 sec, 63.31 MB]                                                                                                                                                                         [bootstrap]
Including /usr/share/drush/commands/pm/updatecode.pm.inc [0.74 sec, 64.06 MB]                                                                                                                                                     [bootstrap]
Executing: wget --version
Running: /usr/share/drush/drush.php  --root='/srv/www/mysite.net/public' --uri='http://default' batch-process '923' --backend  2>&1 [1.77 sec, 69.6 MB]                                                                          [command]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [2.87 sec, 69.65 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [2.87 sec, 69.65 MB]                                                                                                                                                             [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 6. [2.87 sec, 69.65 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [2.87 sec, 69.65 MB]                                                                                                                                                       [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.31 root directory at /srv/www/mysite.net/public [2.87 sec, 69.65 MB]                                                                                                                                         [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [2.87 sec, 69.65 MB]                                                                                                                                                       [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [2.87 sec, 69.66 MB]                                                                                                                                                                [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [2.87 sec, 69.66 MB]                                                                                                                                              [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_database() [2.87 sec, 69.66 MB]                                                                                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [2.87 sec, 69.66 MB]                                                                                                                                                               [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_full() [2.87 sec, 69.66 MB]                                                                                                                                                       [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_login() [2.87 sec, 69.66 MB]                                                                                                                                                      [bootstrap]
Successfully logged into Drupal as Anonymous (uid=0) [2.87 sec, 69.67 MB]                                                                                                                                                         [bootstrap]
Found command: batch-process (commandfile=core) [2.87 sec, 69.67 MB]                                                                                                                                                              [bootstrap]
Initializing drush commandfile: user [2.87 sec, 69.67 MB]                                                                                                                                                                         [bootstrap]
Batch process has consumed in excess of 50% of available memory. Starting new thread [2.87 sec, 69.67 MB]                                                                                                                             [batch]
Command dispatch complete [2.87 sec, 69.67 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                       [notice]
Peak memory usage was 64.05 MB [2.87 sec, 69.67 MB]                                                                                                                                                                                  [memory]
Undefined index: drush_batch_process_finished batch.inc:61 [2.87 sec, 69.67 MB]
```

Which is presumably it refilling the table before going back to normal behavior. Has anyone else found the cache_update solution didn't work? Am I misunderstanding what I need to do?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'dump the cache_update table', it has to be emptied:
      mysql -u root -p;
      use drupal;
      delete from cache_update;
      \q

Answer (score 1):

I "solved this" by updating drush from its default apt-get version (4.5) to the latest dev branch (5.0-dev).

I did this by running:

`sudo drush self-update`

By this point I'd already flushed `cache_update` so it's entirely possible both steps are needed to solve the problem.

Comment: If updating drush is an option I agree. You'll save a lot of headaches and gain a ton of features with the newer versions of Drush. I would recommend moving to 7 though as it's the current stable version. http://www.drush.org/